# Working from home - VPN Routing

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, fortigate

We have a FortiGate VPN, on which we once configured that all vpn clients (who work from home) have all their traffic go through the VPN.

However, now we want only the traffic that goes into the company to go through the VPN, but not all their 'outer' traffic (web surfing, etc.).

Could you please advise where to change the settings?

Comment: The feature you are looking for is called [Split Tunnel](https://help.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/54/Content/FortiOS/fortigate-sslvpn-54/SSLVPN_Examples_54/Split_Tunnel.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `Split Tunnel` feature that can be configured on FortiGate VPN [like this](https://help.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/54/Content/FortiOS/fortigate-sslvpn-54/SSLVPN_Examples_54/Split_Tunnel.htm).